# How to reduce an array's inner array value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

if I have the array like that:

```
array(
   array('id'=>123,'name'=>"Ele1"),
   array('id'=>12233,'name'=>"Ele2"),
   array('id'=>1003,'name'=>"Ele4"),
   array('id'=>1233,'name'=>"Ele5")
)
```

That's the data I get and I want to effeciently remove 2nd value of every inner array. (e.g. "Ele1", "Ele2". .... )

here is what I do:

```
$numEle = count($arrayA);
$_arrayB = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$numEle ; $i++)
{
 array_push($_arrayB ,  $arrayA[$i]['id']); 
}
```

Instead of have a for loop to read and assign the value to a new array. What is the best way to do it?  any php build-in function I should use?

like array_map?

I currently do that:

---

**Thanks all for the answer.  They all work. :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using PHP 5.3 the solution can be quite elegant:

```
$b = array_map(function($item) { return $item['id']; }, $arrayA);
```

On PHP < 5.3 you would have to create a callback function

```
function mapCallback($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}
$b = array_map('mapCallback', $arrayA);
```

or use [`create_function()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.create-function.php) to create a dynamic callback function (I won't show this, because it actually hurts my eyes ;-))

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = array(
   array('id'=>123,'name'=>"Ele1"),
   array('id'=>12233,'name'=>"Ele2"),
   array('id'=>1003,'name'=>"Ele4"),
   array('id'=>1233,'name'=>"Ele5")
);

function reduce($a, $b)
{
        $a[] = $b['id'];
        return $a;
}

var_dump(array_reduce($s, 'reduce'));
```

Comment: Although this solution works as expected, I personally think that `array_reduce()` is not the correct function for this use case as it's not a reduce-operation but rather a map-operation (in the context of map&reduce).

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: in context of map-reduce - reduce part can reduce the mapped data in any way. It can even actually not reduce it at all.

Comment: OK, it just *feels* not really as if it's the correct function. But as it works, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways:

Using array_walk:

```
array_walk($a, function(&$b) { unset($b['name']); });
```

Using array_map:

```
$b = array_map(function($el) { return array('id' => $el['id']); }, $a);
```

Simplifying your own example:

```
foreach($a as $key => $el)
    $b[] = array('id' => $el['id']);
```

Comment: Note that the first example modifies the array by reference. Make a copy first if you need the original intact.